# S3 - Copying lots of data with batch operations and crr, without losing files

Tags: amazon-s3

I have a huge bucket with millions of files, and the bucket is being used constantly and new files are being added. I would like to start backing the bucket up to another region, and I've found that using CRR to backup new files and copying existing files with batch operations would be the way to go.

Setting up the CRR first would result to duplicate files and possible versioning problems, as the new files could be replaced by the old ones.

Doing the Batch Operation first and CRR after would result to some files not being copied.

If both are being made at the same time, everything should be fine - the CRR should propably start whenever the manifest file is getting created. But I have some suspicions for this approach, and the results should get checked somehow.

What is the best way to approach this problem?

Comment: Can I ask... what do you wish to achieve by "backup up" to another region? Is there a disaster scenario you wish to safeguard against?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Yes, this is part of DR strategy. Of course I have versioning enabled in the original bucket, but I want to be 100% that no files will be lost in case of disaster.

Comment: Amazon S3 replicates files to 3+ data centers. The change of losing data is _very_ small (11x9s of durability). It's better than the durability in your own data center. Are you sure that you need to replicate between regions, too? You'll be paying for twice the storage, plus Data Transfer costs. Versioning protects you from accidental deletion. If you lock-down permissions, you can limit the likelihood of intentional malicious deletion.